# How can i merge two drives in same HDD uaing Windows 10 or Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, drive

I have one SSD(Win10 installed) and a HDD(for Ubuntu and apps for Win10). I installed Ubuntu 16.04 for the dual-boot alongside Windows10. I've created 150GB free partition from HDD but while i was intalling the Ubuntu, i've created a partition for ubuntu from Ubuntu GUI (not that 150GB part i created early from Win). Now Ubuntu and Win10 both are working great but when i try to merge that 150GB with rest of the HDD for Win apps, it says "This process will cange basic disks to dynamics..." then i choose Yes and it drive turns to yellow instead of blue and says "There Is Not Enough Space Available on the Disk(s) to Complete This Operation". How can i merge this two partitions?
[image: Partition screen]

Comment: You can also using the Windows Partition Manager, right click on the partition you want to remove and delete it. Then right click on the *(D:)* partition and select *Expand* and Windows will guide you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a third party partitioning software (`Gparted` in Ubuntu or `AOMEI Partition Assistant` in Windows) to merge unallocated space with the local drive you want.